# Process returned -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
 printf("Transactional Shell Command Test.\n");
 while(1) {
  printf("Queue:");
  char input[500];
  fgets (input, 500, stdin);
  if(strstr(input, "qb-write")){
    printf("These are the commands you have queued:\n");
    FILE *cmd = popen("cat /home/$USER/.queueBASH_transactions", "r");
    char buf[256];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), cmd) != 0) {
      printf("%s\n",buf);
    }
    pclose(cmd);
  }
  system(strncat("echo ",strncat(input," >> /home/$USER/.qb_transactions",500),500));
  usleep(20000);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

I am attempting to make a concept for a transactional shell, and I'm having it output every command you enter into a file in the user's home directory. It's not completely finished, but I'm doing one part at a time. When I put in any input to the "shell", it crashes. Codeblocks tells me "Process returned -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)" and then the usual info about runtime. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does Codeblocks not have an integrated debugger?

Comment: How about presenting specific program input with which the crash can be reproduced?

Comment: Note also that your particular usage of `strncat()` does not provide the protection against buffer overflow that you probably suppose it does.

Comment: @JohnBollinger this program always reproduces undefined behaviour...

Answer (score 4):

`strncat` appends to its first argument in place, so you need to pass it a writable buffer as the first argument. You're passing a string literal (`"echo "`), which depending on your compiler and runtime environment may either overwrite unpredictable parts of the memory, or crash because it's trying to write to read-only memory.

```
char command[500];
strcpy(command, "echo ");
strncat(command, input, sizeof(command)-1-strlen(command));
strncat(command, " >> /home/$USER/.qb_transactions", sizeof(command)-1-strlen(command));
system(command);
```

As with the rest of your code, I've omitted error checking, so the command will be truncated if it doesn't fit the buffer. Also note that repeated calls to `strncat` are inefficient since they involve traversing the string many times to determine its end; it would be more efficient to use the return value and keep track of the remaining buffer size, but I'm leaving this as a follow-up exercise.

Of course invoking a shell to append to a file is a bad idea in the first place. If the input contains shell special characters, they'll be evaluated. You should open the log file and write to it directly.

```
char log_file[PATH_MAX];
strcpy(log_file, getenv("HOME"));
strncat(log_file, "/.qb_transactions", PATH_MAX-1-strlen(log_file));
FILE *log_file = fopen(log_file, "a");
…
while (1) {
    …
    fputs(cmd, log_file);
}
fclose(log_file);
```

(Once again, error checking omitted.)

Comment: Your suggested of `strncat()` is inappropriate, in that it does not protect from buffer overruns, which is after all the main reason ever to prefer `strncat()` to `strcat()`.  The third argument is the maximum number of bytes to copy, so in order to protect from buffer overrun, that argument needs to take into account the original length of the string in the destination buffer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, fixed (and I added a note that this isn't a good approach anyway, but I'm not going to rewrite the program completely).